# Using mod_rewrite to pass requests to CodeIgniter in a subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to pass requests from the root of my url to a subfolder without redirecting using mod_rewrite. (Note: I'm doing this on Rackspace Cloud Sites.)

I took the CI .htaccess, moved it up to the root folder, and changed it from this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which gives me an internal server error. I don't believe this sort of this has an error log, which is probably why I've always considered mod_rewrite to be alchemy.

Maybe you can see what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the htaccess file? In the `/ci/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the mod_rewrite, its the server. I was able to run that no problem on my server. If you could provide a url, I can look more. But as it stands, it seems to be the server its running on.